# Where are saved Instagram videos stored on my device?

Tags: instagram

To be clear, these are videos I have taken on the device using Instagram, not other peoples videos. Its videos I have taken then pressed the "save" button before sharing/posting. I have several videos over time I  want to download to my PC.

Seems to be the only way to even find them on the device is in the Instagram app where you go to post on story and it browses all the media on your device, if I scroll down a while I can see the videos, but it is not filtered or organized.

I have browsed the device storage IE

This PC\Pixel 3\Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.instagram.android

To only find a few files there. They have to be on the device because I can search them when posting to timeline/story, but cant seem to find them.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung.

I found my saved instagram stories under [phone name]\Movies\Instagram

Answer (score 0):

Go into your gallery and find an album called *Instagram*. It should pop up. If not, what did you save, posts or stories?